# Workflow with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, geolocation

I just need to know where to start. I'm developing an app with Meteor framework, where I need to have let's say a custom marker, which I get from user's input, so this marker shows up in a place where user stands through geolocation. I need to get this input when a user taps a button like "i'm here", so what's the best way to make it so? Some JS on button? Any examples would be appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dburles:google-maps](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps) . The documentation is well written and easy to use. Use `GoogleMaps.maps.exampleMap.instance` to set the current location on the button click.Grab the users location using either HTML5's location ability or a cordova plugin that provides the same functionality, depending on the app's user base. You could also completely eliminate the need of the button and initialize the map with the users location. See the above package documentation.

Comment: Thank you, will use your answer